# Would Death be weak against fate?

Tags: magic

I want to make a story were a omnipotent god made himself bored so he wanted to have some fun so summons every mythological gods and other beings and embodiments.

That omnipotent god then ordered them to give their power to a chosen individual (it can be anything: human, elves, humanoid swords, beast, etc...) and they will lose their power (but they will be strong as planetary or star destructors) and guide their chosen individual but they can't obstruct their freedom like even if satan was evil his chosen one is good natured.

My main character will have the embodiment of death powers and the more strong he becomes the more he will lose his humanity. He will become true to his nature but because the god wanted to have fun he will let them have their emotions.

The main character will become sadist evil cruel. If a chosen one were to kill a chosener in a set period of time before they become powerful they can have their power but its 50/50.

So, in short I wanted my main character to become overpowered but without becoming servant of fate or weaker then it. I want my main character to be associated with fate and time or let his servant like grim reapers cooperate with with fate and time servants to work. But my main character is free to do whatever the heck he wants, but I cant do that it will leave plot holes.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you are asking here. I suggest to edit your question to make it clearer. - This is what I understand: there are "gods" of which one is death and another is fate, and you are wondering why would death opt to cooperate with fate. - Off topic: check your grammar and spelling, and paragraphs are your friends.

Comment: Sorry im not good at english.

Comment: And what's "MC" and what's "OP"?

Comment: @swswsws English skills aren't a problem here - we can fix spelling and grammar.  What is important is making the question fairly clear.  Right now, it's difficult to see what you're asking.

Comment: @Pᴇᴛᴇ Main Character and Overpowered

Comment: @swswsws, I think my edit comes close to what you want, if there is something wrong with the way it is redacted you can always [edit](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/72165/edit) your question. In particular, I still can't fully parse "guide them but they can't obstruct there freedom like satan chosen one is goodd" Edit: I'm guessing you mean that the god can't go against the free will of the chosen one, and the satan thing is a bad redacted example. And also I have no idea what are the plot holes you are worried about.

Comment: @swswsws For my curiosity: What exactly is death's power?

Comment: I think it might be better on http://writers.tackexchange.com

Comment: @AlexandervonWernherr von WernherrDeath Embodiment | Superpower Wiki | Fandom powered by Wikia and Fate Embodiment | Superpower Wiki | Fandom powered by Wikia .

Answer (score 5):

Stories about characters that are OP can be a bit boring. It's all about limitations and working their way round them, with no limitations, what's the story.

Death is the ultimate reality, everybody dies, but Fate decides *when* they die. What this means is that while Death has a job to do, making sure people die when they're supposed to, Fate gets to have all the fun. Fate decides which farmboy gets to be the hero, get the girl (or boy), slay the dragon, save the princess, and win half the kingdom. Death simply follows along behind and cleans up the mess.

To say who is more powerful in the way you're asking. Death is a worker, but Fate is the boss.

Comment: Then should  I just use the god  to change the systme or just kill the fate  let the mc have it?

Comment: @swswsws, I'm not entirely sure how your system works, but you could consider a "you get what you kill" plus a highlander style "there can only be one", however "I'm not fated to die now, but you are" is a tough one to overcome.

Comment: @Separatrix can fate influence someone stronger or same position as him ?

Comment: @swswsws, that's up to you in your world

Comment: @Separatrix is there way to make my mc free from obstetrical of fates? So that Mc can kill anyone without fate deciding but MC underling need to flow the rules.

Comment: @swswsws, the easiest way to do that is to say that only important people have fates. Only when he's trying to kill someone with a fate does it matter. But remember there are many knights whose fate it is to be eaten by the dragon before the knight whose fate it is to kill the dragon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54172/discussion-between-swswsws-and-separatrix).

Comment: Not _everybody_ dies. Gods don't die unless something really bad happens. Some heroes are rewarded by being made immortal -- for example, Hercules. Other people are made immortal for other reasons -- for example, Ganymede was made immortal because Zeus liked him, and Mary the wife of Joseph was made immortal (in some versions of the myth) because gave birth to God the Son.

Comment: @AlexP All the old pantheons are dead. Demoted from Gods to myths and children's stories, that is how Gods die. All that has a beginning, has an end.

Answer (score 1):

**Mythology**

Since you will be working with personifications, you can put them in struggle. Although to avoid problems with the powers, I suggest being careful how you define them. In particular, a larger pantheon will be helpful to divide the powers among more beings.

For example, you could have one deity be the one that sets the life span of the mortals, another the one that make sure they die at their right time, another will take the soul to the underworld, etc…
Perhaps people grow old because of another deity, and perhaps if a person has a violent death it is the duty of yet another one to make sure the soul do not stay in the corpse.

Using that idea, you can imagine the scenarios of what will happen, if one of them stop doing their works (people never age, people are immortal, there is a ghost infestation, there is a zombie infestation, etc…).

Below I present an extensive (but not exhaustive) list of possible gods of death and gods of fate that you may use. Note: I have given them mythology agnostic names (you may still guess on which deities I based the descriptions, beware that often it is more than one); you do not need to stick with the names I use.

Choose your pantheon carefully.

**God of Death**

Various roles take the name of "god of death" depending on the mythology. In some mythologies, several of these deities are the same, in others they are different entities, and perhaps some may not exist depending on the mythology you are looking at:

- Lord of the underworld, this god is a ruler and guardian of the realm of the deceased souls. Note: there are three variants, one is the embodiment of the realm itself, another is a king set in place by the gods, and the other one is incites people to die.
- Underworld guardian, the deceased souls should not return to our world, the living should not enter. It is the duty if this god to guard the entrance and stop transposers. Note 1: there are variants, one is the embodiment of the gates/river and another is the one who ferries the death to the other side. Note 2: There might be different versions if there are different underworlds or regions of the underworld.
- Burial guardian, this deity guards the tombs and physical remaining of those who die. Note: it might actually be a god for the tomb and another for the remains... or multiple for the remains, like in Egyptian mythology there are custodies for various organs. It may or may not include the idea of preparing the soul for the underworld.
- Lord of the roaming spirits, perhaps not all souls go to the underworld... some stay here, and this deity watch for them and keeps them calm... or not.
- Deity of change and rebirth, death is not the end... when something dies something is born, when something is born something dies, this deity watch over the transition. Note: it might actually be two gods.
- Lord of decay, if you need to blame somebody for making people grow old and die that is this deity, if it weren't because of the lord of decay people could live virtually forever. Note: could also be a deity of misfortune, could also bring mental illness and nightmares.
- Judge of the deceased, this god will receive the souls in the underworld and judge them, either by going over their acts in life or by performing some test. The judgement could be to carry the soul to a different region of the underworld. Note: this god or servants of it could be in charge of keeping record of all the actions people do in life, there are three variants of that: 1) they write it as it happens, 2) the record has always existed, they just pull it and protect the record, 3) what happens is what they write.

Note: I based the list presented above in the more prominent mythologies to my judgment... I could be missing a few variants of "god of death" in there.

I want you to notice that there are "god of death" that could also be considered "gods of demons" or "gods of time"

**God of Fate**

First off, when we talk about "god of fate" we often mean the Moirai/Parcae/Norns, which are the incarnation of destiny. They can be and often are considered associated with death (as such, I list it in the prior section of this post), although they are also often associated with justice in distribution of material goods... Therefore, I will start the list for "god of fate" with that one:

- Deity of distribution, this deity knows what is fair and what is not, you may ask their oracle for advice.
- Deity of prosperity, fortune is an endless cycle that flows from prosperity to disaster and back, it is the duty of this deity to keep that in equilibrium.
- Deity of potential, when a person is born, that person receives a fortune: a life span, virtues and a duty to fulfill in life. People can thank this deity for that, people may ask its oracle to know their fortune.
- Deity of destined love, there is a perfect soul mate for each one, people can ask this deity to help him or her find it.
- Deity of irrevocable curses, the deity that makes people pay their sins (it could be judge of the deceased).
- Deity of causality, this deity protects the laws of nature, makes sure things happen the way they should happen. It would be this deity the one making sure “supernatural” things do not happen. In particular, this deity will oppose to the use of magic. I would use this deity or a variant of this deity for the one making sure the souls do not inhabit “inanimate” objects or stay in the corpses (you may also use the burial guardian for that).
- Deity of old age, this deity will grant people fame and wisdom to compensate their ageing and decay.
- Deity of appropriate time, this deity takes care of things happening in the correct time they should, to do so, this deity watch over the cycles of daytime, seasons, etc… this deity may also watch over events of significance, making sure they happen at the right time, may also grant the gift of prophecy.
- Deity of doom, the work of this deity is to ensure the demise of the living happens when it should happen. This deity will grant a peaceful natural death.
- Divine mediator, this deity will take the pleas and sacrifices that people make and will speak for them to the gods and champion their causes. People may thank this deity when they fortune changes for good.
- Lord of human destiny… plot twist: there is no free will, this deity governs over humans, and perhaps this deity is drunk, blind or outright cruel and uses humans for sick games.
- Lord of time, the personification of time itself, the things that has passed and the things to come. This deity is outside of the concept of time of the physical world, allowing it to know all that happened and all that will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Fate decides who and when, Death decide how. 
But adding free will seems against fate. Unless you incorporate the free will in fate. As in Greek tragedies.
The fate is known but because people may interpret fact differently they make decisions that bring them to fulfilling the prophecy.
So you character can think about how people die ("I hope bucket of sharp knifes fall on your head"), so to escape this the figure that living on a mounting where you don't know anyone will stop people from dying (you can't think about someone you don't know).
The way to not populate your world with undying people is fate deciding only on important people death. She don't care about peasants or merchant death if they don't play a part in her scheme. They die on normal basics. 
Then all the people who are very lucky in not having any dangerous adventures (like drinking and hunting at the same time) live for a very long time. Which became boring for them. So they seek "the one who bring calm". And then play on his nerves so he wish for their death.

Comment: Well my mc is human so he have free will to decide.

Comment: Just like Oedipus. He had free will to go he wanted, at time he wanted. He just went where the fate "predicted". You have two choices: A) the fate is not know so you can't counter it B) the fate is known but because it take under consideration your counter you can't counter it.